# Trigger updation error - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql

I have a trigger on my stock movements table and am trying to update the stock table using it. However once the first record gets written to movements any additional records throws the above error.

Not sure how to resolve it.

See below SQL

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigUpdateStock`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trigUpdateStock` AFTER INSERT ON `material_document`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(MATERIAL) INTO @count FROM `stock` WHERE MATERIAL = NEW.MATERIAL
                                                   AND BATCH = NEW.BATCH;
        IF @count > 0 THEN
            SELECT `MATERIAL`, `BATCH`, `ST_STATUS`, `CONSIGN`, `LOCATION`, `STOCKIST`, `CUSTOMER`, `VENDOR`, `QUANTITY`, `UOM`, `COST`, `VALUE`, `CURRENCY`, `ENTRY_DATE`, `ENTRY_TIME`
                INTO @mat, @batch, @st_status, @cons, @loc, @stkist, @cust, @vend, @qty,
                     @qty, @uom, @cost, @val, @curr, @date, @time
                FROM `stock`
                WHERE `MATERIAL` = NEW.MATERIAL
                  AND `BATCH` = NEW.BATCH;
            SET @qty = @qty + NEW.QUANTITY;
            SET @val = @val + NEW.VALUE;
            SET @cost = @cost + NEW.COST;
            UPDATE `stock` SET `QUANTITY` = @qty,
                               `VALUE` = @val,
                               `COST` = @cost
                         WHERE `MATERIAL` = NEW.MATERIAL
                           AND `BATCH` = NEW.BATCH;
        ELSE
            SELECT ST_STATUS INTO @st_status 
                FROM document_type
                WHERE DOC_TYPE = NEW.DOC_TYPE;
            INSERT INTO `stock` (`MATERIAL`, `BATCH`, `ST_STATUS`, `CONSIGN`, `LOCATION`, `STOCKIST`,                                                  `CUSTOMER`, `VENDOR`, `QUANTITY`, `UOM`, `COST`, `VALUE`, `CURRENCY`,                                            `ENTRY_DATE`, `ENTRY_TIME`)
                        VALUES (NEW.MATERIAL, NEW.BATCH, @st_status, NEW.CONSIGN, NEW.LOCATION,                                                     NEW.STOCKIST, NEW.CUSTOMER, NEW.VENDOR, NEW.QUANTITY, NEW.UOM,                                                  NEW.COST, NEW.VALUE, NEW.CURRENCY, NEW.ENTRY_DATE, NEW.ENTRY_TIME);
        END IF;


    END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your `SELECT ... INTO` selects 15 columns into 16 variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have select one less column in `SELECT` statement

like you have 15 column selected

> SELECT `MATERIAL`, `BATCH`, `ST_STATUS`, `CONSIGN`, `LOCATION`,
>   `STOCKIST`, `CUSTOMER`, `VENDOR`, `QUANTITY`, `UOM`, `COST`,
>   `VALUE`, `CURRENCY`, `ENTRY_DATE`, `ENTRY_TIME`

But you have  specified 16 variable to hold

> INTO @mat, @batch, @st_status, @cons, @loc, @stkist, @cust, @vend,
>   @qty,
>                        @qty, @uom, @cost, @val, @curr, @date, @time

That's why it is giving error.

Comment: thanks, yes i noticed it myself that i had added @qty twice. Tried to close this yesterday but it didnt allow me to.